# sed Command adding space at start of line

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use the sed program to replace two lines of text in a config file using bash variables, the line replacement works however there is a extra space at the start of the line.

My commands are as follows:

```
replacement="computer_id = $server_ref"
```

(where $server_ref is a user entered variable)

and then:

```
sed "/computer_id/c \ ${replacement}" -i slapos.cfg
```

The other line being replaced uses just the same commands just changes a different variable in the config file.

The ouput of this change looks like

```
 computer_id = something
```

when it should be

```
computer_id = something
```

which results in crashing the program using the config as it is not excepting that space.

Comment: Maybe you just have to remove the whitespace in your sed command.

Comment: What's the `c \ ` before `${replacement}`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: it's the `sed` command to change the entire matching line; but it's tricky to use because it may or may not require newlines, backslashes, whitespace etc.

Comment: @tripleee, didn't know that. So it searches for lines with `computer_id` and replaces the whole line with ` \ ${replacement}` in this case? (What's with SO not changing that last thing to code?!)

Comment: The shell interpolates the value of `${replacement}`. But this small box isn't really the place for extended tutorials ... /-:

Comment: @tripleee, nevermind, I read it from the man page. (not so clear though). Seems like `sed "/computer_id/c \${replacement}" -i slapos.cfg` should work for him.

Comment: @Shahbaz I found that didnt work as it wouldnt then use the value for replacement but would rather just take `\${replacement}` as the value

Comment: Maybe still try with a double backslash? You're in a double-quoted string here.

Comment: @tripleee yours worked perfect so all is good its a much better way of doing it that I hadnt thought of so thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be better to do it like this:

```
sed -i "s/^\\(computer_id = \\).*/\\1${server_ref}/" slapos.cfg
```

The program which reads the configuration file isn't very robust if extra whitespace crashed it.

Comment: Perfect worked like a charm, and the team working on that end of the system will be notified about the lack of handling white space :P